# Attempt Windows Authorization but fall back on Custom Login

Tags: c#, iis-7.5, httpmodule

I am working with a module that worked in previous versions of IIS.

http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t94333-re-how-do-i-create-a-httpmodule-to-authenticate-in-aspnet.html

It no longer works because of the Integrated framework, and I cannot change it back to Classic.

The need is for the client to attempt to access the web site and if they are a windows or domain user with access to the site, according to our database, they will be logged in automatically. If not they will be taken to the login page.

The entire site is run off of the default.aspx page which is dynamically generated per call so we cannot have a separate login page.

Does anyone know of a module or method to make this work in IIS 7/7.5?

Edit:
Below is the javascript that the module generates. It appears as though I always jump down to where I return
location.replace("/default.aspx?abortScreening=true");

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
<title>Loading ...</title>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    function canAuthenticate() 
    { 
        try 
        {
        alert("Try canAuthenticate");
            var dom = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument.4.0");
            dom.async = false;
            dom.load("CredentialsScreeningRequiresAuthentication.aspx?ReturnUrl=");
        }
        catch(e)
        {
            return false;
        }
    return true;
    }
    if (document.cookie.length != 0)
    {
        if (canAuthenticate())
        {
            location.reload();
        }
        else 
        { 
            location.replace("/default.aspx");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        location.replace("/default.aspx?abortScreening=true");
    }
</script>
<noscript>
"Your browser does not support JavaScript or has scripting disabled, which prevents credentials screening from working."
 Please click <a href="/default.aspx?abortScreening=true">here</a> to go to the requested page without authentication.
</noscript>
</body></html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This simply cannot be done without using a separate login page.  If it could, there would be solutions out there, and as you've probably found by googling, none can be found.

You have three options.  Go back to Classic mode, use a separate login page, or live without this functionality.

Comment: So what I ended up doing was using an Ajax Error Handler. I catches the  401 error sets a flag to tell the server Windows Auth failed and then redirects them back the page allowing the user to log in.

Comment: @Levi - Creative solution.  I like it.